# How can I add tabpage to tabcontrol dynamically and add label to tabpage

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol, tabpage

I'm trying to add some Tabages to an existing TabControl named "EMER_AUTO_TabContorl" and controlled by emer_num_textbox.

As the picture below,I should be get "A Group"/"B Group"/"C Group", but "C Group"/"B Group"/"C Group".

[image]

And this is my code.

```
Dim group_name As String() = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"} 'my group name
Dim mytabPage As TabPage = New TabPage 
Dim myLabel As Label = New Label
Dim emer_groupNum As Integer 'my input number
Try
        emer_groupNum = Emer_Num_TextBox.Text 
        EMER_AUTO_TabControl.TabPages.Clear() 'Clear my tabControl
Catch           
End Try

For i = 1 To emer_groupNum

   With myLabel
       .Text = "123"
       .Location = New Point(6, pos1_Y)
   End With

   With mytabPage
      .Text = group_name(i - 1) & " Group"         
      .Controls.Add(myLabel)
   End With

   EMER_AUTO_TabControl.TabPages.Add(mytabPage)               
Next
```

Beside Label text "123" doesn't show on TabPages.

Comment: Try debugging your code for a start. If you haven't debugged - set breakpoints and stepped through the code, not just run it - then you shouldn't be posting here. If you have debugged then you should have more information to provide. Apart from that, if you expect to add more than one `TabPage` to your `TabControl`, wouldn't you need to create more than one `TabPage`? How many `TabPages` do you create?

Comment: Switch from a TextBox to a NumericUpDown control.  Then you can set the minimum to 0 and the maximum to the length of the array.  Now you'll always have a valid number that is within range of what is required.

Answer (score 0):

You are re-using the same tabpage and label each time.  Move the 'New' inside the for loop, as below:

```
Dim group_name As String() = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"} 'my group name
Dim mytabPage As TabPage 
Dim myLabel As Label 
Dim emer_groupNum As Integer 'my input number
Try
        emer_groupNum = Emer_Num_TextBox.Text 
        EMER_AUTO_TabControl.TabPages.Clear() 'Clear my tabControl
Catch           
End Try

For i = 1 To emer_groupNum
   myLabel = New Label
   With myLabel
       .Text = "123"
       .Location = New Point(6, pos1_Y)
   End With

   mytabPage = New TabPage
   With mytabPage
      .Text = group_name(i - 1) & " Group"         
      .Controls.Add(myLabel)
   End With

   EMER_AUTO_TabControl.TabPages.Add(mytabPage)               
Next
```

**EDIT**

You may also like to change how you test for a correct integer input as with the Try/Catch currently the For loop is run regardless.  Maybe try something like this:

```
   If Integer.TryParse(Emer_Num_TextBox.Text, emer_groupNum) Then
        For i = 1 To emer_groupNum
            ' Loop code here
        Next
    Else
        ' Handle incorrect input
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Option Strict.

You should test with .TryParse if the text box has a string that can be converted to an Integer.

Never write an empty Catch. Your code will just swallow errors and you won't know what has gone wrong. In this code there is nothing that should go wrong with proper checking of user input.

I think your problem is declaring your label and tab page outside of the loop. This only creates a single label  and tab page. On each iteration of the loop you change the properties of the single controls and readd the same this to the collection. Declare your controls inside the loop and you will get a new instance of the controls.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim group_name As String() = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"} 'my group name
    Dim emer_groupNum As Integer  'my input number
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, emer_groupNum) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in the box.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim pos1_Y As Integer = 3
    TabControl1.TabPages.Clear() 'Clear my tabControl
    For i = 1 To emer_groupNum
        Dim mytabPage As TabPage = New TabPage
        Dim myLabel As Label = New Label
        With myLabel
            .Text = "123"
            .Location = New Point(6, pos1_Y)
        End With
        With mytabPage
            .Text = group_name(i - 1) & " Group"
            .Controls.Add(myLabel)
        End With
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add(mytabPage)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build all the TabPages at Form Load and store them in a List, then simply repopulate the TabControl from that list:

```
Private Groups As New List(Of TabPage)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim group_names As String = "ABCDEFGHIJ"
    For i As Integer = 1 To group_names.Length
        Dim mytabPage As New TabPage
        mytabPage.Text = group_names(i - 1) & " Group"
        Groups.Add(mytabPage)

        Dim myLabel As New Label
        With myLabel
            .Text = "123"
            .Location = New Point(6, pos1_Y) ' <-- Not sure if "pos1_Y" changes?
        End With
        mytabPage.Controls.Add(myLabel)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Emer_Num_TextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Emer_Num_TextBox.TextChanged
    Dim i As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(Emer_Num_TextBox.Text, i) Then
        If i >= 0 AndAlso i <= Groups.Count Then
            EMER_AUTO_TabControl.TabPages.Clear()
            For Each tab As TabPage In Groups.Take(i)
                EMER_AUTO_TabControl.TabPages.Add(tab)
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```